# LINQ - Subquery or LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Tags: linq

I am trying to optimize my LINQ query performance, and I've noticed a lot of LEFT OUTER JOINs being generated. I know that in SQL, there are some cases in which a single row subquery works better than the equivalent LEFT OUTER JOIN.

For example:

Query 1:

```
select f.FacilityName, p.Id PatientId, u.DOB, (select u2.NameComputed from adm.Staffs s inner join dbo.AspNetUsers u2 on s.UserId = u2.Id where s.Id = p.StaffId) AssignedTo
from ptn.Patients p
inner join dbo.AspNetUsers u on p.UserId = u.Id
inner join hco.Hcos f on p.HcoId = f.Id
where p.IsRemoved = 0
```

Query 2:

```
select f.FacilityName, p.Id PatientId, u.DOB, u2.NameComputed
from ptn.Patients p
inner join dbo.AspNetUsers u on p.UserId = u.Id
inner join hco.Hcos f on p.HcoId = f.Id
left outer join adm.Staffs s on p.StaffId = s.Id
left outer join dbo.AspNetUsers u2 on s.UserId = u2.Id
where p.IsRemoved = 0
```

Query 1 takes less than a second. Query 2 takes about 45 seconds. If I wanted to make sure LINQ is structured in such a way as to take advantage of this in some cases, how would I go about doing that? That is, is there a way to write a LINQ statement that produces a subquery instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: It depends of the query provider used (e.g. EF6, EF Core etc.), but in general you cannot control ORM generated SQL.

Comment: Is it a typo that your second left outer join in Query 2 has `u.Id` and not `u2.Id`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo - fixed now. Thanks.